# Set maximum value in DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the follow data point in panda dataframe:

```
DateTime                Data
2017-11-21 18:54:31     1
2017-11-22 02:26:48     2
2017-11-22 10:19:44     3
2017-11-22 15:11:28     6
2017-11-22 23:21:58     7
2017-11-28 14:28:28    28
2017-11-28 14:36:40     0
2017-11-28 14:59:48     1
```

I want to apply a function to convert all Data values bigger than 1 to 1:
Is there a way to combine the following two lambda functions in one (like a else statement)?

```
[(lambda x: x/x)(x) for x in df['Data'] if x > 0]
[(lambda x: x)(x) for x in df['Data'] if x <1 ]
```

end result desired:

```
DateTime                Data
2017-11-21 18:54:31     1
2017-11-22 02:26:48     1
2017-11-22 10:19:44     1
2017-11-22 15:11:28     1
2017-11-22 23:21:58     1
2017-11-28 14:28:28     1
2017-11-28 14:36:40     0
2017-11-28 14:59:48     1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`clip_upper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.clip_upper.html):

```
df['Data'] = df['Data'].clip_upper(1)
```

Or use [`ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ge.html) (`>=`) for boolean mask and convert to `int`, if no negative values:

```
df['Data'] = df['Data'].ge(1).astype(int)

print (df)
              DateTime  Data
0  2017-11-21 18:54:31     1
1  2017-11-22 02:26:48     1
2  2017-11-22 10:19:44     1
3  2017-11-22 15:11:28     1
4  2017-11-22 23:21:58     1
5  2017-11-28 14:28:28     1
6  2017-11-28 14:36:40     0
7  2017-11-28 14:59:48     1
```

But if want use list comprehension (it should be slowier in bigger DataFrame):

```
df['Data'] = [1 if x > 0 else x for x in df['Data']]
print (df)
              DateTime  Data
0  2017-11-21 18:54:31     1
1  2017-11-22 02:26:48     1
2  2017-11-22 10:19:44     1
3  2017-11-22 15:11:28     1
4  2017-11-22 23:21:58     1
5  2017-11-28 14:28:28     1
6  2017-11-28 14:36:40     0
7  2017-11-28 14:59:48     1
```

**Timings**:

```
#[8000 rows x 5 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [28]: %timeit df['Data2'] = df['Data'].clip_upper(1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 308 µs per loop

In [29]: %timeit df['Data3'] = df['Data'].ge(1).astype(int)
1000 loops, best of 3: 425 µs per loop

In [30]: %timeit df['Data1'] = [1 if x > 0 else x for x in df['Data']]
100 loops, best of 3: 3.02 ms per loop

#[800000 rows x 5 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [32]: %timeit df['Data2'] = df['Data'].clip_upper(1)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.32 ms per loop

In [33]: %timeit df['Data3'] = df['Data'].ge(1).astype(int)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.76 ms per loop

In [34]: %timeit df['Data1'] = [1 if x > 0 else x for x in df['Data']]
1 loop, best of 3: 274 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

Numpy solution with `np.clip` -

```
df['Data'] = np.clip(df.Data.values, a_min=None, a_max=1)
df

              DateTime  Data
0  2017-11-21 18:54:31     1
1  2017-11-22 02:26:48     1
2  2017-11-22 10:19:44     1
3  2017-11-22 15:11:28     1
4  2017-11-22 23:21:58     1
5  2017-11-28 14:28:28     1
6  2017-11-28 14:36:40     0
7  2017-11-28 14:59:48     1
```

Pass `a_min=None` to specify no lower bound.

Comment: This is a great answer and np is really powerful, however, i'll pick Jezrael as best answer since it uses datafram's internal function. I appreciate it nonetheless.

Comment: @user97662 not a problem. I can respect your decision. Happy coding.

Comment: @user97662 Although I should bring your attention to the fact that my answer is 9 times better than jezrael's fastest answer. Take a look at my timings. If performance is important, I encourage you to reconsider.