# Why are numpy functions so slow on pandas series / dataframes?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy

Consider a small MWE, taken from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47881048/4909087):

```
DateTime                Data
2017-11-21 18:54:31     1
2017-11-22 02:26:48     2
2017-11-22 10:19:44     3
2017-11-22 15:11:28     6
2017-11-22 23:21:58     7
2017-11-28 14:28:28    28
2017-11-28 14:36:40     0
2017-11-28 14:59:48     1
```

The goal is to clip all values with an upper bound of 1. My answer uses `np.clip`, which works fine.

```
np.clip(df.Data, a_min=None, a_max=1)
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
```

Or,

```
np.clip(df.Data.values, a_min=None, a_max=1)
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
```

Both of which return the same answer. My question is about the relative performance of these two methods. Consider -

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

%timeit np.clip(df.Data, a_min=None, a_max=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 270 µs per loop

%timeit np.clip(df.Data.values, a_min=None, a_max=1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 23.4 µs per loop
```

Why is there such a massive difference between the two, just by calling `values` on the latter? In other words...

**Why are numpy functions so slow on pandas objects?**

Comment: Isn't the latter acting as a "view" on the numpy array? In that case numpy perhaps first needs to convert it to a numpy array internally, and these are thus Python calls, which are slower (but this is only a hypothesis).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, Hmm, I don't believe so... Calling `df.values` creates a new array each time, although I'm willing to be corrected about that.

Comment: If the DataFrame is a single block (no mixed dtypes) then it doesn't create a new array; otherwise it does.

Comment: I think the comparison is not for the same function here. Numpy generally delegates functions to the object's method, if there is any. Since df['Data'] has a clip method, it is probably using the pandas version.

Comment: Another interesting comparison would be comparing NumPy and pandas funcs that do the same job. If they are both slow alike on the same pandas objects, then the question would be why is working with objects slower than regular arrays.

Comment: @ayhan Interesting... are there any rules, sources, or relevant links? I encourage you to flesh this out in an answer, it would really help me out (this has been biting me like mad). Also, if you could show me an example where calling `values` _doesn't_ help, that'd nail it.

Comment: @Divakar Yup, good point. I think the 2 questions are closely related.

Comment: [Jeffrey Tratner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DpyhdO4aM04)'s talk is really good. [Here](http://www.jeffreytratner.com/slides/pandas-under-the-hood-pydata-seattle-2015.pdf) are slides. He starts talking about block manager in slide 35. Let me try to step into both versions to see if I can come up with a complete answer.

Comment: Numpy aims to redirect to `pandas.Series.clip` function, but the arguments are different, and then it fallsback on the `asarray(column).clip(..)` function.

Comment: Have you read [Enhancing Performance - Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html)?

Comment: @user32185 I've seen it, but what if it? is there something in there that is relevant to the question?

Comment: @ayhan I've put a bounty on the question, maybe that'd motivate you to answer. ;-)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes, it seems like `np.clip` is a lot slower on `pandas.Series` than on `numpy.ndarray`s. That's correct but it's actually (at least asymptotically) not that bad. 8000 elements is still in the regime where constant factors are major contributors in the runtime. I think this is a very important aspect to the question, so I'm visualizing this (borrowing from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44468758/5393381)):

```
# Setup

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def on_series(s):
    return np.clip(s, a_min=None, a_max=1)

def on_values_of_series(s):
    return np.clip(s.values, a_min=None, a_max=1)

# Timing setup
timings = {on_series: [], on_values_of_series: []}
sizes = [2**i for i in range(1, 26, 2)]

# Timing
for size in sizes:
    func_input = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 30, size=size))
    for func in timings:
        res = %timeit -o func(func_input)
        timings[func].append(res)

%matplotlib notebook

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

for func in timings:
    ax1.plot(sizes, 
             [time.best for time in timings[func]], 
             label=str(func.__name__))
ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax1.set_yscale('log')
ax1.set_xlabel('size')
ax1.set_ylabel('time [seconds]')
ax1.grid(which='both')
ax1.legend()

baseline = on_values_of_series # choose one function as baseline
for func in timings:
    ax2.plot(sizes, 
             [time.best / ref.best for time, ref in zip(timings[func], timings[baseline])], 
             label=str(func.__name__))
ax2.set_yscale('log')
ax2.set_xscale('log')
ax2.set_xlabel('size')
ax2.set_ylabel('time relative to {}'.format(baseline.__name__))
ax2.grid(which='both')
ax2.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

It's a log-log plot because I think this shows the important features more clearly. For example it shows that `np.clip` on a `numpy.ndarray` is faster but it also has a much smaller constant factor in that case. The difference for large arrays is only ~3! That's still a big difference but way less than the difference on small arrays.

However, that's still not an answer to the question where the time difference comes from.

The solution is actually quite simple: `np.clip` delegates to the `clip` **method** of the first argument:

```
>>> np.clip??
Source:   
def clip(a, a_min, a_max, out=None):
    """
    ...
    """
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'clip', a_min, a_max, out=out)

>>> np.core.fromnumeric._wrapfunc??
Source:   
def _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds):
    try:
        return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
    # ...
    except (AttributeError, TypeError):
        return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
```

The `getattr` line of the `_wrapfunc` function is the important line here, because `np.ndarray.clip` and `pd.Series.clip` are different methods, yes, **completely different methods**:

```
>>> np.ndarray.clip
<method 'clip' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects>
>>> pd.Series.clip
<function pandas.core.generic.NDFrame.clip>
```

Unfortunately is `np.ndarray.clip` a C-function so it's hard to profile it, however `pd.Series.clip` is a regular Python function so it's easy to profile. Let's use a Series of 5000 integers here:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 100, 5000))
```

For the `np.clip` on the `values` I get the following line-profiling:

```
%load_ext line_profiler
%lprun -f np.clip -f np.core.fromnumeric._wrapfunc np.clip(s.values, a_min=None, a_max=1)

Timer unit: 4.10256e-07 s

Total time: 2.25641e-05 s
File: numpy\core\fromnumeric.py
Function: clip at line 1673

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
  1673                                           def clip(a, a_min, a_max, out=None):
  1674                                               """
  ...
  1726                                               """
  1727         1           55     55.0    100.0      return _wrapfunc(a, 'clip', a_min, a_max, out=out)

Total time: 1.51795e-05 s
File: numpy\core\fromnumeric.py
Function: _wrapfunc at line 55

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    55                                           def _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds):
    56         1            2      2.0      5.4      try:
    57         1           35     35.0     94.6          return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
    58                                           
    59                                               # An AttributeError occurs if the object does not have
    60                                               # such a method in its class.
    61                                           
    62                                               # A TypeError occurs if the object does have such a method
    63                                               # in its class, but its signature is not identical to that
    64                                               # of NumPy's. This situation has occurred in the case of
    65                                               # a downstream library like 'pandas'.
    66                                               except (AttributeError, TypeError):
    67                                                   return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
```

But for `np.clip` on the `Series` I get a totally different profiling result:

```
%lprun -f np.clip -f np.core.fromnumeric._wrapfunc -f pd.Series.clip -f pd.Series._clip_with_scalar np.clip(s, a_min=None, a_max=1)

Timer unit: 4.10256e-07 s

Total time: 0.000823794 s
File: numpy\core\fromnumeric.py
Function: clip at line 1673

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
  1673                                           def clip(a, a_min, a_max, out=None):
  1674                                               """
  ...
  1726                                               """
  1727         1         2008   2008.0    100.0      return _wrapfunc(a, 'clip', a_min, a_max, out=out)

Total time: 0.00081846 s
File: numpy\core\fromnumeric.py
Function: _wrapfunc at line 55

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    55                                           def _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds):
    56         1            2      2.0      0.1      try:
    57         1         1993   1993.0     99.9          return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
    58                                           
    59                                               # An AttributeError occurs if the object does not have
    60                                               # such a method in its class.
    61                                           
    62                                               # A TypeError occurs if the object does have such a method
    63                                               # in its class, but its signature is not identical to that
    64                                               # of NumPy's. This situation has occurred in the case of
    65                                               # a downstream library like 'pandas'.
    66                                               except (AttributeError, TypeError):
    67                                                   return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)

Total time: 0.000804922 s
File: pandas\core\generic.py
Function: clip at line 4969

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
  4969                                               def clip(self, lower=None, upper=None, axis=None, inplace=False,
  4970                                                        *args, **kwargs):
  4971                                                   """
  ...
  5021                                                   """
  5022         1           12     12.0      0.6          if isinstance(self, ABCPanel):
  5023                                                       raise NotImplementedError("clip is not supported yet for panels")
  5024                                           
  5025         1           10     10.0      0.5          inplace = validate_bool_kwarg(inplace, 'inplace')
  5026                                           
  5027         1           69     69.0      3.5          axis = nv.validate_clip_with_axis(axis, args, kwargs)
  5028                                           
  5029                                                   # GH 17276
  5030                                                   # numpy doesn't like NaN as a clip value
  5031                                                   # so ignore
  5032         1          158    158.0      8.1          if np.any(pd.isnull(lower)):
  5033         1            3      3.0      0.2              lower = None
  5034         1           26     26.0      1.3          if np.any(pd.isnull(upper)):
  5035                                                       upper = None
  5036                                           
  5037                                                   # GH 2747 (arguments were reversed)
  5038         1            1      1.0      0.1          if lower is not None and upper is not None:
  5039                                                       if is_scalar(lower) and is_scalar(upper):
  5040                                                           lower, upper = min(lower, upper), max(lower, upper)
  5041                                           
  5042                                                   # fast-path for scalars
  5043         1            1      1.0      0.1          if ((lower is None or (is_scalar(lower) and is_number(lower))) and
  5044         1           28     28.0      1.4                  (upper is None or (is_scalar(upper) and is_number(upper)))):
  5045         1         1654   1654.0     84.3              return self._clip_with_scalar(lower, upper, inplace=inplace)
  5046                                           
  5047                                                   result = self
  5048                                                   if lower is not None:
  5049                                                       result = result.clip_lower(lower, axis, inplace=inplace)
  5050                                                   if upper is not None:
  5051                                                       if inplace:
  5052                                                           result = self
  5053                                                       result = result.clip_upper(upper, axis, inplace=inplace)
  5054                                           
  5055                                                   return result

Total time: 0.000662153 s
File: pandas\core\generic.py
Function: _clip_with_scalar at line 4920

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
  4920                                               def _clip_with_scalar(self, lower, upper, inplace=False):
  4921         1            2      2.0      0.1          if ((lower is not None and np.any(isna(lower))) or
  4922         1           25     25.0      1.5                  (upper is not None and np.any(isna(upper)))):
  4923                                                       raise ValueError("Cannot use an NA value as a clip threshold")
  4924                                           
  4925         1           22     22.0      1.4          result = self.values
  4926         1          571    571.0     35.4          mask = isna(result)
  4927                                           
  4928         1           95     95.0      5.9          with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
  4929         1            1      1.0      0.1              if upper is not None:
  4930         1          141    141.0      8.7                  result = np.where(result >= upper, upper, result)
  4931         1           33     33.0      2.0              if lower is not None:
  4932                                                           result = np.where(result <= lower, lower, result)
  4933         1           73     73.0      4.5          if np.any(mask):
  4934                                                       result[mask] = np.nan
  4935                                           
  4936         1           90     90.0      5.6          axes_dict = self._construct_axes_dict()
  4937         1          558    558.0     34.6          result = self._constructor(result, **axes_dict).__finalize__(self)
  4938                                           
  4939         1            2      2.0      0.1          if inplace:
  4940                                                       self._update_inplace(result)
  4941                                                   else:
  4942         1            1      1.0      0.1              return result
```

I stopped going into the subroutines at that point because it already highlights where the `pd.Series.clip` does much more work than the `np.ndarray.clip`. Just compare the total time of the `np.clip` call on the `values` (55 timer units) to one of the first checks in the `pandas.Series.clip` method, the `if np.any(pd.isnull(lower))` (158 timer units). At that point the pandas method didn't even start at clipping and it already takes 3 times longer.

However several of these "overheads" become insignificant when the array is big:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000000))

%lprun -f np.clip -f np.core.fromnumeric._wrapfunc -f pd.Series.clip -f pd.Series._clip_with_scalar np.clip(s, a_min=None, a_max=1)

Timer unit: 4.10256e-07 s

Total time: 0.00593476 s
File: numpy\core\fromnumeric.py
Function: clip at line 1673

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
  1673                                           def clip(a, a_min, a_max, out=None):
  1674                                               """
  ...
  1726                                               """
  1727         1        14466  14466.0    100.0      return _wrapfunc(a, 'clip', a_min, a_max, out=out)

Total time: 0.00592779 s
File: numpy\core\fromnumeric.py
Function: _wrapfunc at line 55

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    55                                           def _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds):
    56         1            1      1.0      0.0      try:
    57         1        14448  14448.0    100.0          return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
    58                                           
    59                                               # An AttributeError occurs if the object does not have
    60                                               # such a method in its class.
    61                                           
    62                                               # A TypeError occurs if the object does have such a method
    63                                               # in its class, but its signature is not identical to that
    64                                               # of NumPy's. This situation has occurred in the case of
    65                                               # a downstream library like 'pandas'.
    66                                               except (AttributeError, TypeError):
    67                                                   return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)

Total time: 0.00591302 s
File: pandas\core\generic.py
Function: clip at line 4969

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
  4969                                               def clip(self, lower=None, upper=None, axis=None, inplace=False,
  4970                                                        *args, **kwargs):
  4971                                                   """
  ...
  5021                                                   """
  5022         1           17     17.0      0.1          if isinstance(self, ABCPanel):
  5023                                                       raise NotImplementedError("clip is not supported yet for panels")
  5024                                           
  5025         1           14     14.0      0.1          inplace = validate_bool_kwarg(inplace, 'inplace')
  5026                                           
  5027         1           97     97.0      0.7          axis = nv.validate_clip_with_axis(axis, args, kwargs)
  5028                                           
  5029                                                   # GH 17276
  5030                                                   # numpy doesn't like NaN as a clip value
  5031                                                   # so ignore
  5032         1          125    125.0      0.9          if np.any(pd.isnull(lower)):
  5033         1            2      2.0      0.0              lower = None
  5034         1           30     30.0      0.2          if np.any(pd.isnull(upper)):
  5035                                                       upper = None
  5036                                           
  5037                                                   # GH 2747 (arguments were reversed)
  5038         1            2      2.0      0.0          if lower is not None and upper is not None:
  5039                                                       if is_scalar(lower) and is_scalar(upper):
  5040                                                           lower, upper = min(lower, upper), max(lower, upper)
  5041                                           
  5042                                                   # fast-path for scalars
  5043         1            2      2.0      0.0          if ((lower is None or (is_scalar(lower) and is_number(lower))) and
  5044         1           32     32.0      0.2                  (upper is None or (is_scalar(upper) and is_number(upper)))):
  5045         1        14092  14092.0     97.8              return self._clip_with_scalar(lower, upper, inplace=inplace)
  5046                                           
  5047                                                   result = self
  5048                                                   if lower is not None:
  5049                                                       result = result.clip_lower(lower, axis, inplace=inplace)
  5050                                                   if upper is not None:
  5051                                                       if inplace:
  5052                                                           result = self
  5053                                                       result = result.clip_upper(upper, axis, inplace=inplace)
  5054                                           
  5055                                                   return result

Total time: 0.00575753 s
File: pandas\core\generic.py
Function: _clip_with_scalar at line 4920

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
  4920                                               def _clip_with_scalar(self, lower, upper, inplace=False):
  4921         1            2      2.0      0.0          if ((lower is not None and np.any(isna(lower))) or
  4922         1           28     28.0      0.2                  (upper is not None and np.any(isna(upper)))):
  4923                                                       raise ValueError("Cannot use an NA value as a clip threshold")
  4924                                           
  4925         1          120    120.0      0.9          result = self.values
  4926         1         3525   3525.0     25.1          mask = isna(result)
  4927                                           
  4928         1           86     86.0      0.6          with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
  4929         1            2      2.0      0.0              if upper is not None:
  4930         1         9314   9314.0     66.4                  result = np.where(result >= upper, upper, result)
  4931         1           61     61.0      0.4              if lower is not None:
  4932                                                           result = np.where(result <= lower, lower, result)
  4933         1          283    283.0      2.0          if np.any(mask):
  4934                                                       result[mask] = np.nan
  4935                                           
  4936         1           78     78.0      0.6          axes_dict = self._construct_axes_dict()
  4937         1          532    532.0      3.8          result = self._constructor(result, **axes_dict).__finalize__(self)
  4938                                           
  4939         1            2      2.0      0.0          if inplace:
  4940                                                       self._update_inplace(result)
  4941                                                   else:
  4942         1            1      1.0      0.0              return result
```

There are still multiple function calls, for example `isna` and `np.where`, that take a significant amount of time, but overall this is at least comparable to the `np.ndarray.clip` time (that's in the regime where the timing difference is ~3 on my computer).

The takeaway should probably be:

- Many NumPy functions just delegate to a method of the object passed in, so there can be huge differences when you pass in different objects.
- Profiling, especially line-profiling, can be a great tool to find the places where the performance difference comes from.
- Always make sure to test differently sized objects in such cases. You could be comparing constant factors that probably don't matter except if you process lots of small arrays.

Used versions:

```
Python 3.6.3 64-bit on Windows 10
Numpy 1.13.3
Pandas 0.21.1
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. One follow up, do these observations also explain the reason for various other numpy functions also being slower on series and data frames? Or it this only specific to clip?

Comment: @COLDSPEED the constant factors probably affect performance across all pandas functions. However clip has a specific asymptotic performance gap because pandas does not call np.clip, it uses np.where. I've tried to unpack this in my answer below.

Comment: Thats kind of indepth. Never saw anything like `%lprun`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Your followup isn't easy to answer because there are lots of NumPy functions that delegate to the method with the same name (but not all do that!) but then it really depends on the implementation of the pandas and numpy method. I expect that pandas generally does more work (because several pandas methods deal more gracefully with NaNs/Nones, object arrays and sometimes offer more functionality) and is therefor slower. But the amount of difference has to be determined on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Fair enough, that's kinda what I expected to hear. I had a fair idea of what I wanted the ideal answer to this question to have and you've ticked all my boxes. Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

Just read the source code, it's clear.

```
def clip(a, a_min, a_max, out=None):
    """a : array_like Array containing elements to clip."""
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'clip', a_min, a_max, out=out)

def _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds):
    try:
        return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
    #This situation has occurred in the case of
    # a downstream library like 'pandas'.
    except (AttributeError, TypeError):
        return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)

def _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds):
    try:
        wrap = obj.__array_wrap__
    except AttributeError:
        wrap = None
    result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
    if wrap:
        if not isinstance(result, mu.ndarray):
            result = asarray(result)
        result = wrap(result)
    return result
```

## rectify：

after pandas v0.13.0_ahl1,pandas has it's own implement of `clip`.

Comment: Thanks. I think you've touched on the focal point, but let me wait for a few more answers.

Comment: @Dark you are right,i just read the comment and i am too quick to give verdict.

Answer (score 7):

There are two parts to the performance difference to be aware of here:

- Python overhead in each library (`pandas` being extra helpful)
- Difference in numeric algorithm implementation (`pd.clip` actually calls `np.where`)

Running this on a very small array should demonstrate the difference in Python overhead. For numpy, this is understandably very small, however pandas does a lot of checking (null values, more flexible argument processing, etc) before getting to the heavy number crunching. I've tried to show a rough breakdown of the stages which the two codes go through before hitting C code bedrock.

```
data = pd.Series(np.random.random(100))
```

When using `np.clip` on an `ndarray`, the overhead is simply the numpy wrapper function calling the object's method:

```
>>> %timeit np.clip(data.values, 0.2, 0.8)        # numpy wrapper, calls .clip() on the ndarray
>>> %timeit data.values.clip(0.2, 0.8)            # C function call

2.22 µs ± 125 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
1.32 µs ± 20.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Pandas spends more time checking for edge cases before getting to the algorithm:

```
>>> %timeit np.clip(data, a_min=0.2, a_max=0.8)   # numpy wrapper, calls .clip() on the Series
>>> %timeit data.clip(lower=0.2, upper=0.8)       # pandas API method
>>> %timeit data._clip_with_scalar(0.2, 0.8)      # lowest level python function

102 µs ± 1.54 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
90.4 µs ± 1.01 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
73.7 µs ± 805 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Relative to overall time, the overhead of both libraries before hitting C code is pretty significant. For numpy, the single wrapping instruction takes as much time to execute as the numeric processing. Pandas has ~30x more overhead just in the first two layers of function calls.

To isolate what is happening at the algorithm level, we should check this on a larger array and benchmark the same functions:

```
>>> data = pd.Series(np.random.random(1000000))

>>> %timeit np.clip(data.values, 0.2, 0.8)
>>> %timeit data.values.clip(0.2, 0.8)

2.85 ms ± 37.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
2.85 ms ± 15.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

>>> %timeit np.clip(data, a_min=0.2, a_max=0.8)
>>> %timeit data.clip(lower=0.2, upper=0.8)
>>> %timeit data._clip_with_scalar(0.2, 0.8)

12.3 ms ± 135 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
12.3 ms ± 115 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
12.2 ms ± 76.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The python overhead in both cases is now negligible; time for wrapper functions and argument checking is small relative to the calculation time on 1 million values. However there is a 3-4x speed difference which can be attributed to numeric implementation. By investigating a bit in the source code, we see that the `pandas` implementation of `clip` actually uses `np.where`, not `np.clip`:

```
def clip_where(data, lower, upper):
    ''' Actual implementation in pd.Series._clip_with_scalar (minus NaN handling). '''
    result = data.values
    result = np.where(result >= upper, upper, result)
    result = np.where(result <= lower, lower, result)
    return pd.Series(result)

def clip_clip(data, lower, upper):
    ''' What would happen if we used ndarray.clip instead. '''
    return pd.Series(data.values.clip(lower, upper))
```

The additional effort required to check each boolean condition separately before doing a conditional replace would seem to account for the speed difference. Specifying both `upper` and `lower` would result in 4 passes through the numpy array (two inequality checks and two calls to `np.where`). Benchmarking these two functions shows that 3-4x speed ratio:

```
>>> %timeit clip_clip(data, lower=0.2, upper=0.8)
>>> %timeit clip_where(data, lower=0.2, upper=0.8)

11.1 ms ± 101 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
2.97 ms ± 76.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

I'm not sure why the pandas devs went with this implementation. `np.clip` may be a newer API function that previously required a workaround. There is also a little more to it than I've gone into here, since pandas checks for various case before running the final algorithm, and this is only one of the implementations that may be called.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why the performance differs is because numpy first tends to search for pandas implementation of the function using `getattr` than doing the same in builtin numpy functions when a pandas object is passed.

Its not the numpy over the pandas object that is slow, its the pandas version.

When you do

```
np.clip(pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5]),a_min=None,amax=1)
```

`_wrapfunc` is being called :

```
# Code from source 
def _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds):
    try:
        return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
```

Due to `_wrapfunc`'s `getattr` method :

```
getattr(pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5]),'clip')(None, 1)
# Equivalent to `pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5]).clip(lower=None,upper=1)`
# 0    1
# 1    1
# 2    1
# 3    1
# 4    1
# dtype: int64
```

If you go through the pandas implementation there is a lot of pre checking work that is done. Its the reason why the functions which has the pandas implementation done via numpy has such difference in speed.

Not only clip, functions 
 like `cumsum`,`cumprod`,`reshape`,`searchsorted`,`transpose` and much more uses pandas version of them than numpy when you pass them a pandas object.

It might appear numpy is doing the work over those objects but under the hood its the pandas function.